# Flaws in attempt at securely sending post data with PHP

Tags: php, security, post

This is my hackish attempt to learn / understand secure(ish) sending of post data. Constructive criticism welcome.

This is just theory, not much code. Also, I'm using PHP's SHA1() in the examples, only because I have put time in understanding its internals. I know theres other (better?) algorithms (example: MD5()) so swap out for your favorite.

1) Server generates a random salt rand(min, max), sends it with the page upon request, computes and stores the SHA1(un:pw:salt) along with the server timestamp of the request (to a database)

1a) Note : salt is sniffable, so assume hacker knows salt (can you un-SHA1() something, to get the SHA1'd data out?)

2) User inputs username and password clicks submit

3) Submit fires a JavaScript function (packed for obfuscation, yeah I know, this does not add true security) that SHA1(un:pw:salt), then posts only that result to the server

3a) Note : encrypted credential is sniffable

4) Server checks that the received credentials match what it stored in the database, and arrive 
 within a timeframe (5 min or so) since the initial request. allow / deny decision is made.

Further requests alter the salt, so even if someone sniffed the encrypted data, it would be useless after
a) user makes new page request
b) timeframe expires

Thoughts?

Edit: also, assume all the strip tags / SQL hacks / < > etc... injections are dealt with appropriately.

Comment: Only real security would be to use https, i think

Comment: yes, barring that of course. good point.

Comment: You can't "un-sha1" something to get the password out. It's a non-reversible hashing function so you have to brute-force the hash. (Oh, and md5 is considered quite a bit less secure.)

Answer (score 3):

Use https and move on to the next problem!

Comment: https is not always available. I come across small clients, a restaurant here, a tattoo shop there, that dont want to pay extra for SSL and all theyd need it for is very minor stuff that is useless to anyone anyway. The security here isnt to keep trade serets secret, more like to have some sense of privacy.

Comment: You can get SSL certificates for 11 USD a year or less - I have seen some free. You can even role your own if you accept the warning.

Comment: @jason - SSL is cheap, like $20 for a certificate that's usable everywhere, or free for a startcom certificate that works in Firefox (or elsewhere with a one-time warning).

Comment: I am aware of SSL. Im more interested in the ways this setup breaks.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of how "Digest" authentication works for HTTP.

If you are interested in learning, [read more about the Digest Authentication method.](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)

Digest authentication does prevent a man-in-the-middle from learning the users password. But, it is vulnerable to attacks where the sniffer can alter traffic too. An active attacker can let the user provide the credential, but modify the body of the request as they like.

Also, as you describe things, the server stores the user's password. This is bad. Password based authentication should only store something *derived irreversibly* from the password.

I recommend that you use SSL and learn how to hash passwords for server-side storage.

Comment: very cool reply. I hadnt considered the attacker intercepting then altering the traffic. edit : you said "the server stores the user's password. This is bad. Password based authentication should only store something derived irreversibly from the password.". See step 1) "...computes and stores the sha1(un:pw:salt)". Unless Im mistaken, I thought I did what you suggest. I could be missing something though, I will think on it.

Comment: @jason - I thought that you picked a new salt for every request, and so you'd need the password each time ("generates a random salt ..., sends it with the page upon request"). But if you did this once, just when they set up their password, that would be okay. However, you'd want a "nonce" for each request that is unique to prevent replay attacks. I thought that's how you were using your "salt."